# Error in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a simple stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `my_proc`(IN mac VARCHAR(12), IN my_field1 INTEGER)
BEGIN 
 UPDATE mytable SET field1 = my_field1 WHERE mac_address = mac;
END$$
```

This gives me:

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4
```

Line 4 is "`BEGIN`"

How is that possible?

Comment: its working fine to me. Didn't throw any error

Comment: Maybe `mac` is empty when you call the procedure?

Comment: add a size to the integer change the delimter in the end.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, see [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/561c02/1). You may have a hidden character after the `BEGIN`, try to delete the line and type `BEGIN` again.

Comment: Are you sure the problems refers to this proc?

Comment: probabily it's phpmyadmin that is giving me this strange error. I don't know why. Using MySQL client works

Comment: phmyadmin is a buggy POS.